# Another Google Earth Treasure Hunt (GETH)

Tags: geography, treasure-hunt

Well, the [first Google Earth Treasure Hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55072/a-google-earth-treasure-hunt-geth) I posted here was solved in less than a day. Let's see how long it takes for this one to be solved. I originally posted this on my CodeAWeek blog. (Link in my profile.)

Imagine that I’ve locked away ten million dollars in a high security vault. The vault is protected by a digital keypad. The correct combination is comprised of decimal latitude and longitude coordinates, accurate to two decimal points. To unlock my vault, you must identify four places in the world and correctly enter their coordinates. For example, if one of the places is the Great Pyramid of Giza, the full coordinates would be: 29.978763°, 31.134297°. We don’t need to be THAT precise, so we round to two decimal points to get: 29.98°, 31.13°. That’s the format I’m looking for when you submit your answer

To get Google Earth to show decimal values instead of degrees/minutes/seconds, click Tools, then Options. Under the tab called “3D View,” under the heading “Show Lat/Long,” check “Decimal Degrees.”

Here are clues to the four locations. Can you figure out where I’m talking about?

1. Here, a babirusa lies in wait, as it has done for the last 40,000 years. It is the oldest of its kind in the world (that we know of as of this writing).
2. In this wondrous museum that isn’t in England, Germany, or the United States, you can hear violins, drums, flutes, pipes, whistles, bells, chimes, pianos, xylophones, and even full orchestras. You can see the instruments being played, but you won’t find people doing the playing.
3. General Sherman may be the largest of his kind, but who has the farthest reach? Outward, not upward. (When I say "kind," I'm speaking generally. I don't mean his specific species.)
4. This (sort of) cave trail is home to the fairies, located within a tourist attraction in the United States that is advertised for hundreds of miles as the place you simply must SEE.

The winner is the first person to answer with all four correct coordinates, numbered 1 through 4.

To ensure that you get the exact coordinates, pull them from the Google Earth pin of the place. In the above pyramid example, you would find the “Great Pyramid of Giza” pin and use that exact location’s coordinates.

Comment: I especially look forward to seeing the answer to #3, Three very different candidates leap to mind, depending on how close to or far from General Sherman's exact kind is acceptable.

Comment: The general kind, not the specific species. I will update the clue.

Comment: Hi, Toby. Please take a look at [this question on the Puzzling "meta" site](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/how-not-to-be-a-spammer-redux) and dial back the promotion of your site a bit. The recommended thing would be to put a link in your profile. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @GarethMcCaughan. I read through your link and updated the post.

Comment: Should probably put the green check on Humn's answer. I only did 1 of the 4!

Comment: Thanks. Will do. I'm still new to stackexchange. I thought I could check both.

Comment: I posted the solution on CodeAWeek and credited the winners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now complete, thanks to
[Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan)
and
[Irishpanda](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16874/irishpanda).

1. > Here, a
   >   [babirusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babirusa)
   >   lies in wait, as it has done for the last 40,000 years.  It is the
   >   oldest of its kind in the world (that we know of as of this writing).
   >
   > > [-5.00° (S), 119.69° (E)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/5%C2%B000'11.0%22S+119%C2%B041'40.0%22E/@-5.0030556,119.6922557,730m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-5.0030556!4d119.6944444)
   > >  
   > >  [A cave in South Sulawesi, Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caves_in_the_district_of_Maros)
   > >  contains
   > >  [40,000 year old art that is thought to depict a babirusa](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/10/141008-cave-art-sulawesi-hand-science/).
   > >  This was found via
   > >  [a museum web page that boasts a babirusa skull](https://blogs.ucl.ac.uk/museums/2016/08/12/specimen-of-the-week-252-the-babirusa-skull/).
2. > In this wondrous museum that isn’t in England, Germany, or the United
   >   States, you can hear violins, drums, flutes, pipes, whistles, bells,
   >   chimes, pianos, xylophones, and even full orchestras. You can see the
   >   instruments being played, but you won’t find people doing the playing.
   >
   > > [52.09° (N), 5.12° (E)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Museum+Speelklok/@52.0908236,5.1188906,225m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c66f5b2ae8f88b:0x95d500d4137e785d!8m2!3d52.0908236!4d5.119581)
   > >  
   > >  [Museum Speelklok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_Speelklok)
   > >  in Utrecht, Netherlands plays instruments robotically.
   > >  This was found with a web search for
   > >  “museum musical instrument robot.”
3. > General Sherman may be the largest of his kind, but who has the farthest
   >   reach? (Outward, not upward.)
   >
   > **Revised revised answer**
   >   (Thank you,
   >    [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55186/another-google-earth-treasure-hunt-geth/55189#comment170070_55189))
   >
   > > [14.03° (N), 78.32° (E)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Thimmamma+Marrimanu/@14.0280369,78.3228904,711m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x3bb3b51707920029:0xd68cc6518a5f9e38!8m2!3d14.0280369!4d78.3250791)
   > >  
   > >  [Thimmamma Marrimanu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thimmamma_Marrimanu)
   > >  is a banyan tree in Andhra Pradesh, India,
   > >  whose *canopy’s* coverage,
   > >  equivalent to a circle 256 feet or 78 meters in radius,
   > >  is reputed to be the broadest of any single-trunk tree in the world.
   > >  [General Sherman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Sherman_(tree))
   > >  is a giant sequoia tree in California, USA.
   >
   > **Previous answer** (not reachy enough)
   >
   > > [-24.96° (S), 140.37° (E)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Neuragully+Waterhole/@-24.9637162,140.3719764,5313m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x6a42ec55273bcceb:0x3a0acc65fa4fa9d9!8m2!3d-24.9637172!4d140.389486)
   > >  
   > >  [Monkira Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_crown_measurement#Largest_recorded_crown_spreads)
   > >  is a tree in Queensland, Australia,
   > >  with a *crown* width of 239 feet or 73 meters.
   > >  This was found with a web search for “widest tree.’
   >
   > **Initial answer**
   >
   > > (Disqualified for being a clonal colony.)
   > >  
   > >  [38.53° (N), -111.77° (W)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/38%C2%B031'36.3%22N+111%C2%B045'56.1%22W/@38.526753,-111.7677747,573m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m9!1m2!2m1!1s+pando+forest,+utah!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d38.5267531!4d-111.7655863)
   > >  
   > >  [The Trembling Giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_(tree))
   > >  is a quaking aspen “tree” in Utah, USA,
   > >  that spans the equivalent of a circle
   > >  1,214 feet or 370 meters in radius.
   > >  It looks like a stand of various trees but is really a collection
   > >  of shoots from a single-organism root system.
   > >  This was once featured on a television show.
   > >  
   > >  I’ve also heard of
   > >  mycelia (mushroom “roots”)
   > >  and desert shrub root systems
   > >  that are single organisms and
   > >  can span very broad areas underground
   > >  with very little presence aboveground.
4. > This (sort of) cave trail is home to the fairies, located within a tourist
   >   attraction in the United States that is advertised for hundreds of miles
   >   as the place you simply must SEE.
   >
   > **Copied**<sub>(with permission)</sub> **revised answer**
   >    
   >   ( SEE and thank
   >    [Irishpanda’s
   >     solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/55238/18129) )
   >
   > > [34.97° (N), -85.35° (W)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Fairyland+Caverns/@34.9734269,-85.3517705,600m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88605c9893b0b0f5:0x4d5a9440a5b03a2f!8m2!3d34.9734269!4d-85.3495818)
   > >  
   > >  [Fairyland Caverns](https://enchantedamerica.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/fairyland-caverns-rock-city-ga/)
   > >  in Georgia, USA.
   > >  
   > >  Related:
   > >  [34.3456°, -84.7194°](https://www.google.com/maps/@34.3455887,-84.7193659,95m/data=!3m1!1e3)
   > >  and
   > >  [34.3405°, -85.7037°](https://www.google.com/maps/@34.340471,-85.7036865,138a,35y,90h,45.01t/data=!3m1!1e3).
   >
   > **Initial answer** (neglected the “SEE” clue)
   >   
   >   [39.55° (N), -107.33° (W)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Glenwood+Caverns+Adventure+Park/@39.5535342,-107.3325628,2259m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xbc8a8d35fc53b8c0!8m2!3d39.5535342!4d-107.3325628)
   >   
   >   Glenwood Caverns Adventure Park, in Colorado, USA,
   >   as reported by a web search for “cave trail fairy shrimp,”
   >   just happens to host nothing less than a
   >   [a Historic Fairy Caves Tour](http://www.glenwoodcaverns.com/cave-tours/historic-fairy-caves-tour/).
   >   You simply *must see* all those historic fairies!

Thank you for another globe-trotting puzzle, Tony Youngblood!
Where to next?

Comment: Now, claim your 10 mn $. :P

Comment: We'll see about #3, @Sid, but the others seem fairly good for 2.5 m$ each . . .

Comment: Now, where did I put that safe....  ;-)

Comment: @humn, you got two right, 1 and 2!  As to number 3, this answer actually works but it's not the one I was thinking of. Look for something that isn't a clonal colony.  And as to number 4, nice answer, but not what I had in mind. The "SEE" clue is significant.

Comment: Re 3, that is one big tree, but it's not the tree I had in mind. The one I'm thinking of spreads way farther than Monrika Monster above ground.

Comment: #4 is easy if you live in a certain geographic region of the U.S. because you can't avoid SEEing signs for the attraction where this feature resides for miles around.

Comment: Perhaps #3 is meant to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thimmamma_Marrimanu ?

Comment: Good one, @Gareth, what a difference between _crown_ and _canopy_!

Comment: For the SEE clue, has none of you ever driven through the Smoky Mountains? There are two features to be found there, that have billboards touting them for quite some ways....

Comment: Humn and @Gareth: regarding the new #3 guess, DING DING DING!

Comment: @Irishpanda, I think you might be on to something...

Comment: If no one gets my hint by my lunchtime, I'll get more specific. I don't want to post a separate answer when someone else has done 3/4 of the work.

Comment: Go ahead and join the road trip, @Irishpanda, you can post #4 and get  credit while giving explicit permission to copy.  My web searches get stuck at Alum Cave Trail and Parton Peaks but haven't found evidence of any  roadside advertisements for either.

Comment: @Irishpanda, now that I take a closer look at your hint (and a map ;-) ), I should say that the place I'm thinking isn't in the Smokey Mountains (although it IS on a mountain), but it is within a 3 hour drive of them. There are probably roadside advertisements for this place in the Smokys if you keep a lookout for them.

Comment: I know exactly the place you mean, but the ads for the place are definitely seen through the Smoky Mts. Some in very precarious places! I'll post my answer for that one later, when I have access to Chrome...I can't get to google earth from work, and my phone is being a right ass at the moment.

Comment: Posted. Also, spoiler markdown is the tool of Satan.

Comment: @TonyYoungblood Ha! I just noticed the little hint in your last comment. I see what you did there!

Comment: I couldn't help myself!

Answer (score 3):

Per comments on the above answer, here is #4. Made an answer so I can spoiler parts, feel free to add to the main answer above!

> 4. This (sort of) cave trail is home to the fairies, located within a tourist attraction in the United States that is advertised for hundreds of miles as the place you simply must SEE.
>
> Anyone that's had to road trip through the American South should be familiar with these guys:
>
> > [image: See Rock City]
> >  [image: Also See Rock City]
>
> There are many variants and they are EVERYWHERE as you pass through
>
> > the Smoky Mountains
>
> They lead you to
>
> > Lookout Mountain in Rock City, GA.
>
> The specific feature here is
>
> > [image: FAIRYLAND]
> >  The entrance to FAIRYLAND CAVERNS, coords 34.97 (N), -85.35 (W)
> >  They are a part of the Rock City cavern complex, decorated with a number blacklight responsive sculptures of fairytale figures.

Comment: Looks better than Disneyland, that's it, I'm hopping a ride, SEE you (and 7 states) there!

Comment: No problem. I only used the link to keep it under spoilers, as the barn images are a dead giveaway.

Comment: And now I figure out how to do it properly. I hate spoiler markdown so much >_<

Comment: Markdown hasn't yet fully solved the spoiler puzzle, one of the most difficult on this site, but now you have, "beautiful"ly!

Comment: You got it!!! I say it's sort of underground  because Fairyland Caverns aren't really caverns. They are in-between two big rocks pressed against each other. Rock City can be a bit cheesy but it's the most beautiful kind of cheese. Ruby Falls and Incline Railway are two more must-sees in Chattanooga. Plus the Tennessee Aquarium.

Comment: When you emphasized SEE like you did, I immediately knew it was either Rock City or Ruby Falls. I remember seeing billboards for both, relentlessly touting them when I was a kid as we traveled back and forth between Ohio and Atlanta.They REALLY want you to see them!

Comment: Just spot me some of that ten million :D

Comment: @TonyYoungblood I was always sad as a kid that I never got to ride the Incline Railway. Lookout Mountain is truly one of the great American tourist traps.